# HttpClient enable cache on server

Tags: .net, caching, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to enable client caching of the System.Net.HttpClient. I have an endpoint at http://localhost:83/api/test that takes 1 second to respond and it sends cache headers back.

If I have this code

```
static async Task MainAsync()
{
    var client = new HttpClient(new WebRequestHandler { CachePolicy = new HttpRequestCachePolicy() }) { BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:83/api/") };
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        var response = await client.GetAsync("test");
        var res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(res);
    }
}
```

It takes one second to execute.

If I put the same code into an api controller

```
    static HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new WebRequestHandler {CachePolicy = new HttpRequestCachePolicy() }) { BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:83/api/") };
    public async Task<string> Get()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync("test");
            var res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        return "ok";
    }
```

And host it in IIS it takes 20 seconds to respond.

What do I need to do in order to enable client cache from server applications?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you should switch to WinHTTP and use another HTTP caching implementation.

There are two HTTP client APIs that .NET Framework uses. One provided by WinINet and another by WinHTTP. .NET Framework uses WinINet by default. But WinINet was developed to work in client applications and it is not suppose to work in server environment. Relevant quote from [Windows Internet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385331(v=vs.85).aspx) page on MSDN:

> ### Where applicable
>
> WinINet does not support server implementations. In addition, it should not be used from a service. For server implementations or services use [Microsoft Windows HTTP Services (WinHTTP)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384273(v=vs.85).aspx).

So in your Web API you need to use WinHTTP. The only way to switch that I know is to use `WinHttpHandler` from [System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler/) NuGet package. But currently this handler do not use HTTP caching. It has no way to set cache policy and it ignores all settings that `HttpClientHandler` respect. See [How do I utilize HTTP caching with WinHttpHandler and HttpClient?](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/25854) issue on GitHub.

To fix this you can implement your own caching mechanism or use existing one like [CacheCow](https://github.com/aliostad/CacheCow) project. It has built-in in-memory storage and it's own implementation of `DelagatingHandler` for `HttpClient`. 
 Note that currently there are some compatibility issues and you need to manually remove reference to .NET Framework System.Net.Http from your Web API project before installing System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler and CacheCow.Clien NuGet packages. Following code snipped demonstrates usage of `WinHttpHandler` and `CachingHandler` from CacheCow.Clien NuGet package:

```
static HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new CachingHandler { InnerHandler = new WinHttpHandler() })
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:83/api/")
};
```

For more information check:

- [Under the Hood: WinINet](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2007/08/21/under-the-hood-wininet/) and [Under the Hood: WinHTTP](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2007/09/07/under-the-hood-winhttp/) articles by CC Hameed
- [CacheCow.Client, using the benefits of HTTP Caching on the client](http://byterot.blogspot.ru/2012/08/cachecow-client-http-aspnet-webapi.html) article by Aliostad
- [Caching in .NET Framework Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/performance/caching-in-net-framework-applications) page on MSDN

Answer (score 1):

Either application pool that your website runs in doesn't have a user profile associated with it or caching is forbidden somewhere in configuration files.

In order to utilize that caching mechanism in IIS you need associate a user profile with application pool, so your website can utilize that profile's temporary files folder. See [IIS Hosted Web API Not Caching Internal HTTP Responses](http://chrisoldwood.blogspot.ru/2015/01/iis-hosted-web-api-not-caching-internal.html) article by Chris Oldwood for more details. Relevant quote from [Application Pool Identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities) page on MSDN:

> ### User Profile
>
> IIS doesn't load the Windows user profile, but certain applications might take advantage of it anyway to store temporary data. SQL Express is an example of an application that does this. However, a user profile has to be created to store temporary data in either the profile directory or in the registry hive. The user profile for the Network Service account was created by the system and was always available. However, with the switch to unique Application Pool identities, no user profile is created by the system. Only the standard application pools (DefaultAppPool and Classic .NET AppPool) have user profiles on disk. No user profile is created if the Administrator creates a new application pool.
>
> However, if you want, you can configure IIS application pools to load the user profile by setting the LoadUserProfile attribute to "true".

Embedded cache mechanism can also be disabled by [`disableAllCaching`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/network/requestcaching-element-network-settings) flag in web or machine configuration file. You need to check this too because this setting can't be overridden programmatically.

Comment: I tried running the app pool as the same user where the console snippet worked. No difference. LoadUserProfile is true. I also added   <system.net>
    <requestCaching isPrivateCache ="false">
    </requestCaching>
  </system.net> to web.config. No difference. Any further suggestions?

Comment: Did you check that there is no `disableAllCaching="true"` in web.config or machine.config on machine that your website runs on?

Comment: Also you may want to use web debugging proxy like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to check that your website actually performs 20 requests and that their response codes are 200 and not 404 for example.

Comment: disableAllCaching is not in machine.config or web.config

Comment: And the requests do indeed return 200 and cache header

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to re-configuring your server, you could cache the result yourself - maybe store it in the session depending on your needs.

Having said that, you've turned an asynchronous call into a blocking call - you should really be using callbacks (or promises).

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question and the purpose of this controller is blocking to test if caching works. No need for callbacks when using async/await